# What's wrong with lc.exe + msbuild? does not generate .dll.licenses file but without any errors

Tags: c#, .net, windows, build, msbuild

this is msbuild log

> Output file "obj\Debug\ProjectName.dll.licenses" does not exist.
>   Using "LC" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
>   Task "LC"
>    Task attempted to find "LC.exe" using the SdkToolsPath value "". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set to the correct value and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location below it.
>
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\NetFX 4.0 Tools\LC.exe" /target:...
>
> Microsoft (R) .NET License Compiler 
>    [Microsoft .Net Framework, Version 4.0.30319.34209]
>    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Generates a .NET Licenses file and adds it to the manifest of the given assembly
>     Usage:
>        lc /target:TargetAssembly /complist:filename [/outdir:path] [/i:modules] [/v] [/nologo]
>
> Options:
>        /target:              Target assembly for the generated licenses file
>        /complist:            Licensed component list file
>        /outdir:              Output directory for the generated licenses >file
>        /i:                   Specify modules to load
>        /v                         Verbose output
>        /nologo                    Suppress the display of the startup banner
>
> Done executing task "LC".

How is that possible? No errors on compile time and no compile result?

Log looks like wrong command line(default help), but it's not true

I copied all command about LC.exe...

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\NetFX 4.0
>   Tools\LC.exe" /target:...

**And that's work when called from command line**, successfully generate file *dll.licenses

Specified path exists! - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\NetFX 4.0 Tools\LC.exe

SDK installed, path in registry correct

Why does not work when called from msbuild?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?